# bind chart data to datepicker to show custom timeline

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, winforms

i a very new to c#

I have created a bar chart  in my WinForms application , by connecting them to MSSQL stored procedure as the data source , but i needed to provide a date picker function (from and to) and when user selects the date , only that much filtered data should be populated to the chart , but whenever i click the update button , the chart is getting data additionally(see the image) instead f filtering.

my procedure for chart:

```
create proc toprej
@fromDate date,
@toDate date
as
select top 10 RejectReason1 as Reason, Sum(NetWt) as Quantity
from IP_Spools
Where status = 'Reject' AND DOE between  @fromDate  and  @toDate
group by RejectReason1
order by Sum(NetWt) desc
go
```

my code for chart in winform:

```
    private void GraphToprej()
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Toprej", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromDate", dtfrom.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toDate", dtto.Value);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Rejcategory.Add(dr.GetString(0));
                    RejSum.Add(dr.GetInt32(1));
                }
                ChartTopRej.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(Rejcategory, RejSum);
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
private void datefil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GraphToprej();
        }
```

here is the image:

[image: every time i click on the button the bars are getting added with same data]

kindly help me how to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you must recreate your graphic object every time you click the button. For this you have to clear the graphics control. for example, you are sending data by date range into a listbox. When you change the date range and send data again, you should clear this listbox with listbox1.Items.Clear().

```
private void datefil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //--> Here you have to clear your graphic object.
    // for example lboxData.Items.Clear();

    GraphToprej();
}
```

You're new to C # so I want to make a suggestion

My advice would be to separate this link with a Class and handle it from a single point. I recommend you to research the subject of **Separation of Concern (SoC)**.

In addition, I suggest you run your code as follows. `Using` block disposes of the object and closes the connection automatically.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    conn.Open();
    //commands
}
```

**UPDATE**

I read the question you wrote in more detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/203060/bind-chart-data-to-datepicker-to-show-custom-timel.html). The problem is that you define **ArrayList** objects in the global scope. In such a definition, the data remains in memory, you need to clear it. You will either define it in method or write it in global scop and create an instance inside the method.

You can try this, I tried it worked

```
private void GraphToprej()
{
    ArrayList Rejcategory = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList RejSum = new ArrayList();

    //then write SqlConnection and other codes...
}
```

or

```
//Global Scope
ArrayList Rejcategory;
ArrayList RejSum;

//Your Method
private void GraphToprej()
{
    Rejcategory = new ArrayList();
    RejSum = new ArrayList();
    
    //then write SqlConnection and other codes...
}
```

Comment: hi @Volkan Barbaros Gurcan ..i tried `charttoprej.series.clear() ;` above the method call , but now i am getting index out of range exception. The actual problem is the chart is getting added with new values every time i click the button instead of updating.